# Application's name disappear Android

Tags: android

I made an Android application, but when I look at it in my device, the appName just disappeared whereas I added it in the manifest and strings.xml. My application is the one at the bottom left

[image]

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.package.package.package"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/countdown_icono"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        // Activities
    </application>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">I can\'t wait!</string>
</resources>
```

If someone could helps :)

**SOLUTION :**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="APP NAME" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: have you tried reinstalling it? never seen something like this

Comment: ok can you please try this? "I can't wait!"

Comment: @Virus, I did it, and it didn't work but also I found the solution. I didn't but anything for MainActivity label, so I just put the name of my app and I see that now she has one. I didn't know MainActivity label was the name we could see one the board...

Comment: @maevy Post your entire `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

inside your **Activity** tag in the AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<activity android:name=".theJavaClassActivity"
              android:label="yourString">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Android Launcher shows the title of the activity that has the `Intent-filter` of `android.intent.action.MAIN`. In this way it is able to show more than one activity icons and titles if your application requires so.